# Why do I immediately segfault when accessing an integer array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, integer

I send initialize the code array to be size 500 before filling it with integers and sending it to this 
function to populate a struct with array values. But when trying to access code[0], the machine crashes.

```
instruction *fetchCycle(int *code, instruction *ir, int pc)
{
  int index = pc * 4;
  printf("accessing code[%d]\n", index);
  ir->op = code[index++];
  printf("accessing code[%d]\n", index);
  ir->r = code[index++];
  printf("accessing code[%d]\n", index);
  ir->l = code[index++];
  printf("accessing code[%d]\n", index);
  ir->m = code[index++];
  printf("accessing code[%d]\n", index);
  return ir;
}
```

This is the function that calls fetchCycle()

```
// takes in a single instruction and executes the command of that instruction
void executionCycle(int *code)
{
  int l, m, sp = MAX_DATA_STACK_HEIGHT, bp = 0, pc = 0, gp = -1, halt = 0, i = 0;
  int data_stack[41] = {0}, reg[200];
  instruction *ir;

  // Capturing instruction integers indicated by program counter
  ir = fetchCycle(code, ir, pc++);
  // printf("5\n");
  while (halt == 0)
  {
    // printf("6\n");
    switch(ir->op)
    { ...
```

And this is the output to the terminal:

accessing code[0]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Instructions are probably not integers. You should access them as bytes in memory with `unsigned char`.

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where is `code` declared and initialized? Is it simply an unintialized pointer?, or pointer already increment beyond the end of what it points to? -- that would sure explain the SegFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snipet:

```
instruction *ir;

// Capturing instruction integers indicated by program counter
ir = fetchCycle(code, ir, pc++);
```

Is problematic, what you are passing to the function is an unitialized pointer `ir` so when the function tries to access it's members it can't, because they are not there.

As for `code` I can't say, since it's a parameter of the function `executionCycle`, I don't know where it points to. You should probably include the caller of that function in the question too.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, if the answer solved the problem don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)